# Google Wallet Subscriptions API

Tags: android-pay

I have found these questions relating to my question, but there has been no development by Google in this area:-

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/in-app-payments/YFaCBDwaF9g

[Does Google Wallet server calls back on every renewal of a subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592992/does-google-wallet-server-calls-back-on-every-renewal-of-a-subscription)

My question is how does one verify that we should continue providing a service to a customer, if we do not know if they are paying. I don't have time to waste checking manually.

Is this feature available yet?

Answer (score 0):

The [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15602071/304683) already answers your question regarding what to expect.

- While the API doesn't send you a renewal postback,
- the API will [send you a cancellation postback](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions#6) for a subscription cancellation (*whenever* Google can't obtain funds for the subscription)