# Is it bad to rely on google subscription cancel callback?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

We are adding subscriptions to our app and I am trying to figure out the best way to verify the user has an active subscription.

[Does Google Wallet server calls back on every renewal of a subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592992/does-google-wallet-server-calls-back-on-every-renewal-of-a-subscription)

The above link answered one of my questions. Basically, an auto-renewing subscription is treated as a subscription with no end date. Google will only notify the the subscription has canceled. I assume google will notify the app that the cancellation has occurred which will then send the request to the server. I don't believe google will notify the server directly since I don't recall ever setting up any endpoints. Now, that doesn't seem that reliable. It seems like a user could easily manipulate the process to not allow the app to send the request to the server (which is seen with a few of the in app purchasing hacks).

Now the only solution I can think of is to have my server pool google every time a subscription is close to expiring. Probably a day after the subscription expired. (give them one free day in case the purchase takes longer).

Comment: Hi @Kalel Wade, did you solve it? Can you share your solution?

Comment: Its been awhile but I believe what I ended up doing was to check google close to or after the subscription was expiring.